# Android - не выходит обращаться к ответу от сервера

Tags: android, java

Есть AssyncTask:

```
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://access.wayplan.ru/register.php");
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "text/html");

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            EditText login = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLogin);
            EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", login.getText().toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password.getText().toString()));

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            String response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");

            Log.i("response :", response);
            return response;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.i("response :", "ERROR 1");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("response :", "ERROR 2: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "error";
        }
```

Вроде бы указал тип данных, нужную кодировку. И, получаю необходимый ответ от сервера (ok).

Вопрос в том, что дальше, я хочу проверить, если пришло "ok", то показать всплывающую подсказку:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressRegister);
        progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button.setText(R.string.auth_register);
        button.setEnabled(true);
        if (result == "ok")
        {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
            toast.show();
        }
    }
```

И вот тут проблема. Потому что, в логе ok пришел, а на экране всплывающая подсказка не появляется. Если убрать if, то подсказка появляется (значит дело не в ней, она работает).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как работать с ответом от сервера?

P.S. На сервере установлен header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ("ok".equals(result))
```

Comment: Спасибо больше. Помогло.